# Should I use require in view functions?

Tags: solidity, struct, require, view

When I call a solidity function to get a struct element, is it a best practice to use `require` and check if the element exists or should I just return the empty values?

Without require:

```
function getStruct(uint256 _id) returns (address, bool) {
  return (structs[_id].addr, structs[_id].boolean);
}
```

With require:

```
function getStruct(uint256 _id) returns (address, bool) {
  require(structElementExists(_id));
  return (structs[_id].addr, structs[_id].boolean);
}
```

Should view functions fail or should they just return empty results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as a matter of style and context.

It is not possible to maintain the confidentiality of information stored in the contract, so as an access-control mechanism, it is pointless.

*In my opinion,* it is often useful to differentiate between a valid request and an invalid request. As in your example, `require(exists())` is a good guard to prevent returning a non-existent instance of something. There are cases where you *want* to return a default, empty instance, and there are cases where there is no good reason why it should occur.

In cases where it's used, it's a good idea to expose the `exists()` function so a client can inspect it before invoking a strict function. That way, there really is no good reason why a client would go out of bounds.

```
function exists(bytes32 key) public view returns(bool doesIndeed) {
  return <expression>;
}

function get(bytes32 key) public {
  require(exists(key),"Can't do that. It doesn't exist");
  return ...
}
```

A client has some options.

```
if(!exists(key)) createIt(key);
// carry on
```

**TL;DR;** It depends on the context.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is generally subjected to opinion; here is mine:

If `structs` is `public` then the `require` statement is pointless, since users will be able to retrieve an "empty" value by calling the implicit getter-function generated by the compiler, i.e., function `structs(uint256)`.

In fact, since the block-chain itself is public, users will be able to retrieve an "empty" value also when `structs` is not `public`, with the only difference being that they will have to "work a little harder" on their off-chain code in order to achieve that.

So my general opinion is that it is pointless to add `require` statements to a constant function which is designated only for off-chain users.

That said, if you designate this function also for on-chain users (i.e., if you intend for it to be called from other contracts), then it might actually be useful to have it "requiring" certain conditions (if such conditions are applicable of course), otherwise any on-chain user calling this function will have to apply these conditions on the returned value every time the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on whether non-existing key is a valid input for your getter or not.  Basically this is not a technical but rather religious question.  Fail-fast adepts would put `require` to make sure caller will never treat empty returned values are a valid structure.

Though, in case live structure may never contain empty values in all fields, returning empty values may be a good way to signal that key does not exists.  Also, such signal is easier to handle from within other smart contracts, because Solidity still lacks `try ... catch`.